# Return Object (with specific key, value types) from function in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose I have a function that needs to return something of type `StringMap<string, boolean>`. An example return that is valid is: `{"required": true}`.

Now, I've read in a tutorial (it's not important which tutorial) you can create a function that has return type of `{ [s: string]: boolean }` and this is the same return type as the StringMap above.

I don't understand how are these two the same return type? And how the second version is even valid?

1. All the return types I have seen in TypeScript have only included the type in the past i.e. boolean, number, any. For example `function (): number {}`. In our second version we use `s: string` which means we give the variable a name, and specify it's type, how are we suddenly allowed to give the variable the name `s`?
2. On top of that we put this string inside an array `[s: string]` as the key in the second version (therefore the key is now an array). While a StringMap has a string as the key.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax is a bit different than you think. It's a unique syntax for defining dictionaries\maps.

`{ [s: string]: boolean }` means: a map, which has a key with type string, and it's values are boolean. The `s` means nothing at all, it could have been anything you want.

(Then why give it a name in the first place? my guess is to make the code more clear, when mapping more complex types. Sometimes you'll want to call the index `id`, sometimes `address`, etc..)

More info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), indexed types is what you want.

The Typescript handbook online isn't the most friendly documentation ever, but I think it's good enough and I recommend everyone who uses typescript to at least skim through it. Especially since in 2.0+ they added a bunch of crazy\awesome type features like mapped types.

Answer (score 2):

The type `{ [s: string]: boolean }` defines an [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) interface.

What you see as an array is just the syntax decided to define the index of the interface.

The name of the key, as far as I know, is ignored and only the type is what matters.

This code `{ [s: string]: boolean }` is defining an indexable interface where the indices are strings and the values are booleans.

I assume that the definition of `StringMap` is as follows:

```
export interface StringMap<T, U> = { [s: T]: U };
```

Which is kind of redundant if you ask me (as the name says that it should be a string map, so the keys should be strings). I would have declared the `IStringMap` interface as:

```
export interface IStringMap<T> = { [key: string]: T };
```

Interfaces in TypeScript just define the "shape" of the object. The previous three definitions have equivalent shapes, so this is perfectly valid:

```
function fn() : IStringMap<boolean> { 
    let myMap : StringMap<string, bool> = { };

    myMap["foo"] = true;
    myMap["bar"] = false;
    myMap["baz"] = true;

    return myMap;
}

let foo: { [bazzinga: string]: boolean }  = fn();
```